# supporting hyperplane of the unit ball

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb R^d: \|x\|_2\leq 1\}$. Show that for all $x \in\partial B$ there is exactly one supporting hyperplane of $B$ that contains $x$.
I need help to show this. My idea is that I can assume $x=(1,0,...,0)\in \mathbb R^d$ because the ball is symmetric.

Comment: Your idea seems fine. The hyperplane has to contain $x$, so what remains is to determine it's normal vector. It seems geometrically obvious that the normal should be $x$.